# Save normalized tensor to png in a loop using pytorch

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, png, tensor

I am working on a GAN and cannot make it work to save images that I transformed into tensors back to “normal” pngs within a loop. The same goes for the tensors that are generated by the Generator.

I applied the following transformation for the original images I am using for the training in the GAN ( I hope i did it the right way):

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
[
transforms.ToPILImage(),
transforms.Resize(img_size),
transforms.CenterCrop(img_size),
transforms.ToTensor(),
transforms.Normalize([0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
]
)
```

When trying to save the tensors as png images in a loop with the following code they do not come out the right way:

```
real_samples = next(iter(train_loader))
for i in range(4):
torchvision.utils.save_image(real_samples[i, :, :, :],
‘Real_Images/real_image{}.png’.format(i))
```

On the left is an example of the original image after transformation and on the right an example of the “wrongly” saved ones:
[image: Comparison of original and wrong saved image]

Can anyone please help me out with saving the images in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply normalization with mean 0.5 and std 0.5, so your images are transformed from range (0., 1.) to (-1., 1.). You should denormalize them and bring back to the original range before saving them.

In your case, simply doing

```
real_samples = real_samples * 0.5 + 0.5
```

before saving should work.

Comment: So I found the solution, while you just gave me the answer @burzan . Thanks for that. I also thought I had to do the de-normalize, but used the normalize function of torchvision.utils. Accordingly, the code for saving the images is

torchvision.utils.save_image(
real_samples[i, :, :, :], ‘Training_Punks/Training_{}.png’.format(i), normalize=True)

How come that worked? Does the normalization with torchvision.utils equal the de-normalization? I don't get it and would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: You can see what it does in the documentation here: https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.utils.make_grid.html?highlight=make_grid#torchvision.utils.make_grid

Basically it takes the minimum and maximum value of the tensor and normalizes it to be in (0, 1) (unless you provide your own range). it won’t always be accurate, so it’s best to either denormalize on your own or pass (-1, 1) as the range